# How to make a simple text editor in Turbo-C++ without Windows API?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

First of all I would like to tell you all that I did a lot of research on Google and elsewhere but to no avail.

I want to know how do I go on about making a text editor in turbo c++ without windows API.
I started making it some time back in turbo c++ and I also learned how to include mouse using int86() function and I implemented that. But time and again I am getting stuck on something or the other. Like right now I am stuck how do I **Highlight** and **Select** the text for right clicking.

Secondly I also learned how to access video memory (however fake or old it may be these days) to have better control over the text.

Also for the text input I am using a large array as I have little knowledge about using Link Lists for such large text input and manipulating it.

Note: I do not want to use any other IDE or any API for it due to purely educational reasons.

Please guide me on how to get this thing go on further till completion. I am willing to learn all additional things to complete it.

PS: This is **Not** a homework. Just for learning purposes.

Comment: Damn, you make me think on the times I was 17yrs old (and that's 15 yrs ago). Respect :)

Comment: Dang! That is quite the goal! +1!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and the +1 lol. But the problem still remains.

Comment: Are you targeting real DOS, or Win32 console?

Comment: You're going to need to read up on data structures -- you've about hit the limit of what you can do with straight arrays.  You could also get the source to one of the simpler OSS editors like ed

Comment: I think its real DOS. And @jthill thanks for telling me  that

Comment: I have been through Turbo C++ and BGI graphics and other stuff in my college days too. But since you are spending time on learning only and not any home assignment, would suggest you spend time on QT. QT is widely used in industry, cross-platform and massively powerful. Much simpler and powerful than other GUI solutions for C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As what I remember, you set video mode by setting the AX (ah:al) register and calling INT 10h [see this](http://www.htl-steyr.ac.at/~morg/pcinfo/hardware/interrupts/inte6l9s.htm).

Then the pixel map is accessed at memory address 0xA000. If you select a video mode f.e. 320x200 with 256 color palette, you can set RGB color palet by writing the color index to port 0x3C8 and then write Red value to 0x3C9, write Green value to 0x3C9 and write Blue value to 0x3C9.

```
// select mode 320x200
asm {
    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 13
    int 10h
}

// set red background (color index 0)
asm {
    mov dx, 0x3c8
    mov al, 0
    out dx, al

    mov dx, 0x3c9
    mov al, 0xff
    out dx, al

    mov al, 0x00
    out dx, al
    out dx, al
}
```

Instead of asm you can also use `outportb` and `inportb`

```
// Set color with index 5 in color palette with outportb:
outportb(0x3c8, 5); // color with index 5
outportb(0x3c9, 0xFF); // red channel value
outportb(0x3c9, 0x00); // green channel value
outportb(0x3c9, 0x00); // blue channel value
```

Change video mode in C, might be something like this:

```
union REGS    regs;
regs.w.ax = 13;
int86(0x10, &regs, &regs);
```

C pointer to graphical pixel map:

```
volatile unsigned char *pixmap = (volatile unsigned char *)0xA000;
// Write a pixel with color index 5 to X:10 Y:25 in 320x200x256 video mode:
pixmap[10 + 25 * 320] = 5;
```

C pointer to text map:

```
volatile char *charmap = (volatile char *)0xB800;
// Write hello world in text-mode
int offset = 0;
charmap[offset++] = 'H';
charmap[offset++] = 'e';
charmap[offset++] = 'l';
charmap[offset++] = 'l';
charmap[offset++] = 'o';
charmap[offset++] = ' ';
charmap[offset++] = 'w';
charmap[offset++] = 'o';
charmap[offset++] = 'r';
charmap[offset++] = 'l';
charmap[offset++] = 'd';
```

Note that all of this stuff asumes you are in DOS mode and I didn't test it. In Windows this will fail and give you segmentation faults or memory access errors...

Comment: asm is a little above my head so can you explain using outportb and inportb. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you're attempting is above your head.  You need to step back and learn some basics, beginning with data structures.  Having a firm understanding of data structures is absolutely essential to solving non-trivial programming problems, and what you're trying to do here is decidedly non-trivial.  It's like telling us you want to build a house but you don't know how to frame walls and don't want to learn.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to do some serious study. (and btw I want to learn, that's what I also said in my question)

Comment: I don't know if it's really worth to study these kind of things, todays programming environments and languages are way more sophisticated. Think you better learn to use higher level frameworks. Unless you really want to stick with DOS or want to write your own OS from scratch ;)

Comment: @WouterH I am doing that simultaneously. It is the utter curiosity that has driven me here, to get to know how it actually works or used to work.

Comment: Then I suggest you start to learn how computers (Intel based in this case) work, what are IO ports, what are interrupts. Then you can lookup ports for the PIC, videocard, Keyboard, timer and do some crazy stuff with it (and even crash your system a lot). Check out interrupts like 21h (dos) 13h (bios) 10h (video) and see what functions they offer... Very interresting stuff, but it won't bring you anywhere these days.

Comment: Any specific reference book for these things?

Comment: I have a very good book, but it's from 1995 and in Dutch. It's called "PC underground" from Easy Computing.

Comment: Not in english? Anyways I'll try to get some books like that and will pursue it, after all getting anywhere is not the only aim. Thanks for all the help Wouter.